# How do I remove my git directory when I accidentally created one in users. Terminal > /Users/juggularvein: is a directory

Tags: git, github

I must have accidentally created a git directory in

> /Users/myusername

So when I tried to create a new one in a folder on Desktop I get this error:

> myusername$ ~ git clone my-git-clone-link
>
> /Users/myusername: is a directory

I must have made my whole user a directory or something when I was practicing the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find `.git` folder inside your directory and delete it. This will remove the git tracking information from the directory.

Comment: How can I find the .git folder when its in my user directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear.

But till what i could understand, 
To remove a directory
`rm - r directory_name`

Comment: I can't find or I'm just not sure how to find the directory since it is in my whole user is turned into a directory.

Comment: Well to find the `.git` directory , wherever you feel you created it, just type a command `ls -al` to check if that `.git` directory is there and if it is there remove it by `rm -r .git`

Comment: I tried that but couldn't find any .git directory. I'm not sure what the issue is but I'll just be using the Git Desktop version for the moment. But thank you for your suggestions!